# How to call std library functions in lldb

Tags: lldb

How does one print out an expression with a std library function in lldb? For example, suppose I want to use `std::string::c_str()` in an print expression. I can see the symbol and disassemble it just fine but cannot seem to use it in an expression call

```
(lldb) image lookup -v -r -n "c_str\("
2 matches found in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib:
        Address: libc++.1.dylib[0x0000000000041da6] (libc++.1.dylib.__TEXT.__text + 264214)
        Summary: libc++.1.dylib`std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::c_str() const
         Module: file = "/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib", arch = "x86_64"
         Symbol: id = {0x000002ec}, range = [0x00007fff8ec8cda6-0x00007fff8ec8cdbe), name="std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::c_str() const", mangled="_ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE5c_strEv"



(lldb) dis -n "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::c_str()"
libc++.1.dylib`std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::c_str() const:
   0x7fff8ec8cda6:  pushq  %rbp
   0x7fff8ec8cda7:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
   0x7fff8ec8cdaa:  testb  $0x1, (%rdi)
   0x7fff8ec8cdad:  je     0x7fff8ec8cdb5            ; std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::c_str() const + 15
   0x7fff8ec8cdaf:  movq   0x10(%rdi), %rdi
   0x7fff8ec8cdb3:  jmp    0x7fff8ec8cdb8            ; std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::c_str() const + 18
   0x7fff8ec8cdb5:  incq   %rdi
   0x7fff8ec8cdb8:  movq   %rdi, %rax
   0x7fff8ec8cdbb:  popq   %rbp
   0x7fff8ec8cdbc:  retq   
   0x7fff8ec8cdbd:  nop
```

But cannot seem to use it in an expression. Seems to always choke on the `std` namespace identifier

```
(lldb) expr std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::c_str($rax)
error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
error: expected unqualified-id
error: 2 errors parsing expression
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an instance method, you have to call it on an object.  In your case, it looks like you want to do something like:

```
(lldb) expr ((std::__1::string *) $rax)->c_str()
(const value_type *) $1 = 0x00007fff5fbff661 "some string here"
```

You really shouldn't have to explicitly name the __1, but lldb doesn't support "inline namespaces" yet (and the clang debug information doesn't say __1 IS an inline namespace, so for now you do.

Comment: That still doesn't work, I get a undeclared identifier std. I guess I'm trying to ask a more basic question: If I can see a function XXXX in the symbol table and dissasemble it via dis -n XXXX, why can't I call it in an expression via expr XXXX(...). Most values of XXXX seem to work just fine but with the std library functions they do not. I'm guesing it is do to the "::" in the name. If that is the case, is there still a way to call that function (e.g. escape the name in some fashion)?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in an app with debug information or without?  If the latter, this isn't going to work.  lldb doesn't currently know how to turn C++ mangled names into the full language structures that produced them, which is what it needs to do to run its expression parser (which is just a built-in version of clang...)  If you are seeing this fail when you DO have debug information, please post an example of the code & debug session where you see this fail.

Comment: This is without debug information so I guess I'm out of luck then trying that method. Thanks